AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add_field'
help, it gives such an error - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'add_field'
@bot.command(name='stats')
async def stats(ctx):
        resultbalance = cursor.execute(f'SELECT balance FROM users WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}').fetchone()
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"**Статистика пользователя - {ctx.author.name}**"),
        embed.add_field(name='**Баланс:**', value= resultbalance[0])


@bot.command(name='stats')
async def stats(ctx):
        resultbalance = cursor.execute(f'SELECT balance FROM users WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}').fetchone()
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"**Статистика пользователя - {ctx.author.name}**")
        embed.add_field(name='**Баланс:**', value= resultbalance[0])

the error you are getting is  because you have a comma after the discord.Embed() function,which is interpretating it as an tuple , remove the comma from the end.

there are no errors without this comma, but when I enter this command into the chat, my bot does not send anything

there could be many reasons for this , share your rest of the code, or try running it by adding some debugging messages.

I have sent a new message in this thread

I found a solution, added: await ctx.send(embed = embed)

@Peaky_001
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import sqlite3
from config import settings

intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True



connection = sqlite3.connect('server.db') 
cursor = connection.cursor() 

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_ready(): 
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users ( 
                name TEXT,                                               
                id INT,
                balance BIGINT,
                lvl INT
                   )""")
    connection.commit()
    
    for guild in bot.guilds:
         for member in guild.members:
              if cursor.execute(f'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
                    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES('{member.name}', {member.id}, {0}, {1})")
                    connection.commit()
              else:
                   pass 
    print('bot connected!')
    await bot.change_presence( status = discord.Status.online, activity = discord.Game('flodreyn'))

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if cursor.execute(f'SELECT id FROM users WHERE id = {member.id}').fetchone() is None:
                    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO users VALUES({member}, {member.id}, 0, 0, 1)")
                    connection.commit()
    else:
        pass

@bot.command(name='stats')
async def stats(ctx):
        resultbalance = cursor.execute(f'SELECT balance FROM users WHERE id = {ctx.author.id}').fetchone()
        embed=discord.Embed(title=f"**Статистика пользователя - {ctx.author.name}**")
        embed.add_field(name='**Баланс:**', value= resultbalance[0])


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
